# What is the fastest way to replace the first occurrence of a set of possible characters in a string?

Tags: regex, performance, nsstring

I have a string beginning with any possible combination of "+" and "0" and want to replace it with "+".

I did it with regEx:

```
NSString *phoneNumber  = @"+000+123"
NSString *regExString   = @"^[+0]+(?=\\d*)";

NSRegularExpression *regEx = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regExString options:0 error:nil];
[regEx replaceMatchesInString:phoneNumber options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [phoneNumber length]) withTemplate:@"+"];

// result: @"+123"
```

It works but takes too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it was 60% faster than the regEx solution:

```
NSInteger posPrefixEnd;

for (NSInteger pos=0; pos <[phoneNumber length]; pos++)
{
   NSString *charAtPos = [phoneNumber substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(pos, 1)];
   if ([charAtPos isEqualToString:@"+"] || [charAtPos isEqualToString:@"0"])
   {
      posPrefixEnd = pos;
   }
   else
   {
      break;
   }
}

NSRange prefixRange = NSMakeRange(0, posPrefixEnd+1);
[phoneNumber replaceCharactersInRange:prefixRange withString:@"+"];
```